# Can I reorder the windows taskbar thumbnails?

Tags: windows-10

I have 4 windows of Firefox opened but I want them to order differently.
I guess they are ordered chronologically by default but I want to reorder them.
I tried drag & drop but that doesn't work.

[image: https://i.imgur.com/5s3aEth.png]

Answer (score 4):

You can use `7+ Taskbas Tweaker` for this purpose which you can download from the following link:

http://rammichael.com/7-taskbar-tweaker

EDIT: Once you download the program you must check "Drag to reorder" shown below.

[image]

Comment: Can you give OP more details, kindly edit your answer and explain

Comment: Can I do it without installing third software? For instance, change values in registry....

Answer (score 0):

Drag (reorder) those tabs in Firefox and the taskbar preview will automatically update.

Comment: This aren't tabs but windows.

Comment: @namespace You mean you opened 4 webpages in separate Firefox windows? I don't think it's possible to reorder then.

Comment: Yes that's what I mean.. That's bad :/

Comment: You can reorder them using third software like "7+ Taskbas Tweaker", the question now, is it possible to edit registry to be able to reorder them